# file synchronization between two open-e storage servers

Tags: backup, storage, replication, synchronization

i am currently trying to find a solution to synchronize two storage servers both running open-e dss 6.

- i need only one-way synchronization (storage A -> storage B)
- my volume is 30TB in size, therefore dss' replication will not work (at least afaik it only supports volumes up to 16TB)
- there are about 1.000.000 files to synchronize

i've tried with rsync but things got very, very slow with a million files.

i have no clue if there are any better solutions for this problem, so any help would be very much appreciated!

Comment: What version of rsync did you use and how much memory did it have?

Answer (score 1):

You could potentially use something like [DRBD](http://www.drbd.org/) to handle the replication.

Comment: yeah, open-e even supports DRBD -- the problem is, that it seems to be limited to volumes up to 16TB. at least with open-e. or is this a general limitation of DRBD?